# PHP creates two files at a time with different files names but with the same content

Tags: php, session, filenames, uniq, file-put-contents

The goal is to create a repository of a custom session files. When I use this code to write data to a session file, php creates two files with different names but with the same content. Why is this happening?

```
$uniqFileName = sha1(uniqid('', true)) . '.sess';
$path = '/storage/sessions/';
$sessionContent = ['name' => 'SomeName', 'age' => 'SomeAge'];
file_put_contents($path . $uniqFileName, serialize($sessionContent));
```

This creates two files at a time with the same content:

```
0b2399001549e543d067ea28c6561a1b752f58a9.sess
685fcb86fc7310d58e1154ca6b6d029630bb6d56.sess
```

The contents of both files:

```
a:2:{s:4:"name";s:8:"SomeName";s:3:"age";s:7:"SomeAge";}
```

It is understood that this will be a class, but the code works the same way in the context of the class and in index.php.

Comment: this code is not enough to track the error. show when and which condition it is running?

Comment: Where are you doing this? Is this in the index.php in the document root?

Comment: It is understood that this will be a class, but the code works the same way in the context of the class and in index.php

Comment: Check your access_log(if you are using apache and have access to it, many shared hosting providers will also give you access to the logs). Check there if you see two requests being made.

Comment: @codeHeart Thank you. You're absolutely right. The problem was in .htaccess file which is twice addressed index.php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since both those names are different using `uniq()`, that means your code is being called twice for sure. Look for that. There must be a loop or 2 calls to this code section. Can't happen by itself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it helped.